# pass parameter to javascript file via $.get

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a shared header for a suite of applications we're using. Currently I'm able to pull in an HTML file and even execute javascript.

```
$("#header-container")
    .load("http://component.balanceinnovations.dev/header.html header", function () {
        $.getScript("http://component.balanceinnovations.dev/js/header.js");    
});
```

This works great, but I'd like to pass header.js a parameter. So I'm attempting this

```
$("#header-container")
    .load("http://component.balanceinnovations.dev/header.html header", function () {
        $.get("http://component.balanceinnovations.dev/js/header.js", { cityID: '4274356' }, undefined, 'script');  
});
```

In `header.js` how can I reference this parameter? If it's even possible.

Comment: Why not simply call a function in `header.js` like `someFunc('4274356')` after it finishes loading? As far as I know you can't do what you're asking because once the javascript downloads it executes under your current document, which has a different querystring.

Comment: By using $.get(url,success ) you are requesting to load a JavaScript File from your server. You cannot pass a parameter in your script . If loading was successful you can use success callback function and pass any parameter into your header.js which already got loaded .

Comment: Yes, it seems calling it in the success function works, it seems to require the header.js to not to be an IIFE, just trying to protect global variables

Answer (score 0):

By using $.get(url,success ) you are requesting to load a JavaScript File from your server. You cannot pass a parameter in your script. 
You can do like this.

```
var cityID = 4274356;
$("#headercontainer").load("http://component.balanceinnovations.dev/header.html header", function () {
       $.getScript( "http://component.balanceinnovations.dev/js/header.js", function( data ) {
        //once download was performed then here you can pass your parameters into header.js.
      });    
 });
```

**Edit :**
In case of using IIFE you can define a global variable before loading `header.js` and change your function like below .

```
(function(cityID) {
  // cityID == 4274356'

})(cityID);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems possible. According to [jQuery's website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) the $.getScript function "is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to..." (see the $.ajax code below). You'll have to use the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to pass data to the server. By adding the data attribute from the [Ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to the $.ajax example on the [getScript page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), it should look something like this...

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://component.balanceinnovations.dev/header.html",
  data: { cityID: '4274356' },
  dataType: "script",
  success: successFn
});

function successFn(data) {
    $("#header-container").html(data);
}
```